# Groundwater interpolation using kriging with external drift

Tags: python, interpolation, kriging

I have a bunch of groundwater measurements that I would like to interpolate taking into account the ground elevation. For this, I was advised to use kriging with external drift. I have tried different things but nothing seems to work well, but since it is my first time using the algorithm I'm not sure if it is because of my lack of understanding or because the data is just 'not good' or poorly distributed.

The 18 measurements and the elevation (drift) can be found below and [HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cl-tU29DB45xrZU_AwxyCC1TrrbOf0C7/view?usp=sharing), respectively.

```
       x          y      h
75077.77  218734.77   2.59
71464.00  215493.00   2.64
72447.62  216517.45   2.17
74454.00  216007.00   1.94
74663.00  215861.00   2.16
74737.00  215818.00   2.15
74869.00  215735.00   2.14
74934.00  215696.00   2.01
74042.00  217333.00   2.12
74153.00  217251.00   2.13
74248.00  217181.00   2.08
74555.00  218086.00   2.02
74682.00  218182.00   2.34
74664.00  218055.00   2.16
74755.00  218020.00   2.43
72142.00  218026.00   2.27
72271.00  217859.00   2.24
72376.00  217796.00   2.09
```

- I'm using python (pykrige module) to work this out.
- When plotted in a histogram the data follow a normal distribution with a slight skewness to the right. Since I read that kriging equations don't make assumptions regarding data distribution I'm not making any transformation.
- The longest distance of points is around 5000 m
- When plotting the semivariance cloud, although we see some increase of variance with distance, the relation is not very strong.

[image]

I tried to adjust the number of lags to see try to fit a model, but it was always looking 'unfittable'. After playing with different things the best I could get was an exponential one.

[image]

I would like to get some feedback because of my lack of experience with the algorithm.

Is the data poorly distributed/too small to you?